# (Possible Duplicate) Could not find or load main class package

Tags: java, class, command-line, package

When I try to run my program in the command line, I get:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Scheduling**

```
package scheduler; 
import java.util.*;

public class Scheduling
{
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
      }
}
```

In the command line, I type: javac Scheduling.java and it compiles fine, but when I try to run: java Scheduling, it loads up that error. While trouble shooting and trying to see what's wrong cause all of my other java files work fine, I noticed it was the package scheduler was the problem. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try compile from root folder:

```
cd ..
javac scheduler/Scheduling.java
```

And then run:

```
java scheduler.Scheduling
```